# error in mapping custom tag in jsp

Tags: java, jsp, custom-tag

When i try map custom tag, i am getting `Error: 500` with a message `File "/customTag" not found`

Here is my attempt:
myTag.tld

```
<taglib version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/j2ee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-jsptaglibrary_2_0.xsd"
    >
    <uri>customTag</uri>
    <tlib-version>1.0</tlib-version>
    <tag>
        <name>multiplier</name>
        <tag-class>myPack.MultiplierTag</tag-class>
        <attribute>
                <name>input</name>
                <required>true</required>
                <rtexprvalue>true</rtexprvalue>
        </attribute>
    </tag>

</taglib>
```

jsp page

```
<%@taglib uri="/customTag" prefix="operator"%>
<%
    String input = request.getParameter("input");
%>
<operator:multiplier input="<%=input%>"></operator:multiplier>
```

When i am trying to access `.tld` file using file name then everything is fine

Comment: Just guessing, but since you have `<uri>customTag</uri>` then maybe try `<%@taglib uri="customTag" prefix="operator"%>` without `/` before `customTag`.

Comment: @Pshemo even that's not working. I attempted that already

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In TLD file: Add short-name and change uri from customTag to /customTag

```
<short-name>operator</short-name>
<uri>/customTag</uri>
```

In JSP

<@ taglib prefix="operator" uri="/customTag" />

Comment: What is the role of <short-name> here

Comment: short-name is optional. Name that could be used by a JSP page-authoring tool to create names with a mnemonic value.

Comment: So <uri> tag is the only tag i need. <short-name> can be eliminated.

Answer (score 1):

I am not JEE expert but I just created my own `tld` based on your example and example from *Head First: Servlets and JSP* and it seems that:

- in `uri` you need to specify name that you will use in `<%@taglib uri="..."` so if it is `<uri>customTag</uri>` then you need to use it as `<%@taglib uri="customTag"`
- your tag doesn't specify `body-content`, which for your example can be set to `empty`

So try with this tld which you can place in `/WEB-INF/tlds/myTag.tld`

```
<taglib version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/j2ee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-jsptaglibrary_2_0.xsd">
    <uri>customTag</uri>
    <tlib-version>1.0</tlib-version>
    <tag>
        <name>multiplier</name>
        <tag-class>myPack.MultiplierTag</tag-class>
        <body-content>empty</body-content>
        <attribute>
                <name>input</name>
                <required>true</required>
                <rtexprvalue>true</rtexprvalue>
        </attribute>
    </tag>
</taglib>
```

For implementation you can use

```
package myPack;

import java.io.IOException;

import javax.servlet.jsp.JspException;
import javax.servlet.jsp.tagext.SimpleTagSupport;

public class MultiplierTag extends SimpleTagSupport {
    private String input;

    public void doTag() throws JspException, IOException {
        getJspContext().getOut().write("Hello " + input + " <br>");
    }

    public void setInput(String input) {
        this.input = input;
    }
}
```

and for demonstration you can use your earlier JSP

```
<%@taglib uri="customTag" prefix="operator"%>
<%
    String input = "World";//request.getParameter("input");
%>
<operator:multiplier input="<%=input%>"></operator:multiplier>
```

Don't forget to republish your project after updating it.